# htaccess RewriteRule for Pretty URL always redirect to index

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to create pretty URLs using RewriteRule in my .htaccess. However instead of linking the alias with specified pages. My web now only redirects to index.php no matter what address I type in.

Below is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /AboutUs.php
```

Is there anything I need to set up prior to this? or is there something wrong with my htaccess? Please help.

Comment: You need to tell us if there is any problem with this.

Comment: Hi anubhave, sorry if the problem is not clear enough. The problem is it ALWAYS redirects to index.php while the code is supposed to redirect to ABOUTUS.php

Comment: ok verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Apparently it does not, it still redirects to Index no matter what URL do I put in, however when I remove the htaccess file, it will give me a 404 error. Any advise?

Comment: If .htaccess is enabled then putting some random text as first line  must generate 500 error

Comment: Ah yes, the 500 error is generated. So I assume the fault is in the code right?

Comment: I fixed the problem, apparently I have edited the wrong file all along. But thanks for your help!